# iPhone HTML5 website on homescreen with jQuerymobile offline splash page?

Tags: iphone, html, jquery-mobile

How do I go about loading a splash to the user if they are offline? I want it to show after the initial loading image, I have a page called gone-offline.jsp but how to detect if user is offline on mobileinit?

I'm not using phone-gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what offline means to your business scnenario. This may sounds silly, but it depends on what your app wants to do. For example:

Does your app want to go offline when it is actually offline and can't reach other websites, or does it want be in offline status when it can't access your webservice.

Assuming you want to test that there is no connection to your webservice I would recommend the following:

1) Make an ajax call every x number of minutes to your webservice to check if it is still online
2) make a common method that handles time outs if your application thinks its online and is offline.
3) make it so that when your application is offline, it is trying to get back online in the background by doing a similar step to step 1.

To do ajax with JQuery see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Note that if you require cross domain json (you may or may not) then you will need to investigate CORS/JSON-P/XSS with iframes.

Comment: I guess I'm not too fussed about a complex solution atm. I want it to hit the splash when it can't communicate /w our servers, it runs an initial authorisation procedure on mobileinit so perhaps the only way to do this is detect an exceptionally long initial AUTH ajax request and if its over 10 seconds or so then redirect user to offline page. Of course the user will then get this message if our servers are simply overloading which isn't great.. Its more simply to serve as a notification if the user is actually offline rather than a blank page,

Comment: Ok have just tried testing that, it doesn't work, it doesn't utilise any locally stored files unless u create a HTML5 manifest, so I will give that a go

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple using javascript.

```
if(navigator.onLine)
{
 //online code here
}else{
 //offline code here
}
```

(done with jQ mobile)